# Soql object has multiple lookups to user

Tags: salesforce, soql

Afternoon,
I am gathering data from the LiveChatTranscript and there are multiple references to user as lookup fields. How do I pick which property I want to use as my reference to user?

**LiveChatTranscript properties**

- LastModifiedById Lookup(User)
- CreatedById  Lookup(User)
- OwnerId  Lookup(User,Group)

**query**

-webroot-/query/?q=select chatkey, caseid, status,requesttime, starttime, endtime,endedby,name,ReferrerUri,platform,location, waittime,body,supervisortranscriptbody, case.description, ownerid,***ownerid.user.alias??*** from livechattranscript where chatkey = '12345'

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `owner` is the field name. It *looks up to* the `user` object. No need to include the object name there. Just drop the `id` potion for `ownerid`.

Use `owner.alias`.